# How to filter with gatsby-cloudinary-plugin

Tags: gatsby, cloudinary

I try to filter a query from cloudinary in gatsby.

I tried this in graphql:

```
query {
       allCloudinaryMedia (
           filter: {
                tags: {
                  eq: "antwerp"
                  }
             }
        ) {
           edges {
            node {
              id
              resource_type
              url
               }
           }
       }
}
```

I tagged a photo in cloudinary as "antwerp". There is no error but nothing shows.

Comment: In Cloudinary we expected something like (in nodeJS): 
 cloudinary.v2.api.resources_by_tag("mytag", 
  function(error, result) {console.log(result, error); });   to get the image url as a result.url or result.secure_url.

Comment: In Gatsby(that is React) we use a query with graphql to a external resource installing a plugin. The plugin give us the posibility of querying the photos in cloudinary. This query works fine as showed above without argument filter. But if we want to select some photos, we need to use the argument filter. Here is what I don't know how to.

Answer (score 0):

I sorted.
After installing the plugin we need to set a configuration for the plugin in the file 'gatsby-config.js' as I did it. But in the options I missed to set the option tags to true.